# Creating a bridge device using nmcli

Tags: command-line, scripts, network-manager, kvm-virtualization, nmcli

I am trying to create a bridge device in Ubuntu 22.04, so I can set it a a default network for KVM guests. I need bi-directional external (non-NAT communication from and to the guests.
I followed [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-network-bridge-with-nmcli-networkmanager-on-linux/) guide and created a BASH script to automate the creation of the bridge device.
I have two problems:

1. The bridge device I've created disappears after a reboot.
2. I need the bridge device (br0) to be set up as a slave to the main Ethernet device (enp6s0).

I **was** able to do all I need from the GUI (`nm-connection-editor`), but, as I've mentioned, I need to auromate this via  a BASH script, since I will be using this script to install 8 workstations.

Can someone point me to the correct way to do it via a BASH script / CLI?
Thank you !

Comment: Both nm and netplan can do it persistently. Does your solution **require** nmcli? Or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: I don't **require** `nmcli,` I just want to create the bridge device and make it persistent between reboots  - from within a BASH script. I'd appreciate a pointer to a suitable guide.
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I really hate working with `netplan`, or any YAML for that matter. Also, it's imperative I use `NetworkManager`, so the users can monitor their connection status in the GUI.